# How to get the data of an ethereum block using geth

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

How can i get a block info from a running ethereum node using geth or nodejs or any other language? For example to get a block data from bitcoin, there is a config file which run a blocknotify.sh file when a transaction is confirmed and in that blocknotify.sh file there is this command : `bitcoin-cli getblock "$@" >> "$@.json"` which gets the block data then i can send a post request of that block data to an api. So i want to do the same thing that is to get the block data from ETH nodes and send a post request to an api when a transaction is confirmed. How can i do this ?

Comment: Why was this down voted? Question seems legit as even I had the same doubt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While running in `geth console`, you can use the web3 library to get block information:

```
> var blockNumber;

undefined
> var blockInfo;

undefined

> web3.eth.getBlockNumber(function(e, r) { blockNumber = r; });

undefined
> blockNumber;

2515149
> web3.eth.getBlock(blockNumber, function(e, r) { blockInfo = r; });

undefined
> blockInfo

{   difficulty: 1319089762,    extraData: "0xd58301070d8650617269747986312e32332e30826c69",    gasLimit: 4700036,  gasUsed: 0,    hash: "0xf9c495b5e5bcd3935aa4a6fd5a43009de29ca7d7be77d4b7cc4c68b8704bc422",  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", miner: "0x94cd009bbba97f30a36845e2025edf7544d62439",    mixHash: "0xb8794a6d1b777f8c6fdf509f04896642f67dab82dc872ae9cbe9bcbf85172972",  nonce: "0x264c013815697c2f",    number: 2515149,    parentHash: "0x0d2b4185aec34d8963b4c0b8fa7abb8604e1452bcb7f7f7d7a75a3d1cfd85f92",  receiptsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",  sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",  size: 537,    stateRoot: "0xc3810c2e763669a6e0219c78990c92b91c634d23810f4bd67144c4d76b9cfe6e",  timestamp: 1516811780,    totalDifficulty: 7642933628775356,    transactions: [],    transactionsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",  uncles: []  }
```

The web3 documentation can be found here: [v0.2x.x](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API), [v1.0](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0)

EDIT - Example transaction info retreival:

```
> web3.eth.getTransaction('0xaebaf7e8207c417f6bb7920f3820e5220738d6825b6f577e3c3d0736d3c95b49', function(e, r) { if (e) console.log(e); else res = r; });

undefined
> res

{   blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",  blockNumber: null,   from: "0x0a78c28257b40d5076ea180bc6a9e4c597c5ea98",   gas: 90000,   gasPrice: 40000000000,   hash: "0xaebaf7e8207c417f6bb7920f3820e5220738d6825b6f577e3c3d0736d3c95b49",  input: "0x",   nonce: 32,   r: "0x902f7a7b7c3e4ebcab47014f9c3b81858cdc4b90ef36d9630adaf30b47ec370f",  s: "0x6f09e7d66dc2146afa108322f433c12b629eadd149e1e113669b6bd2e0cd467e",  to: "0xb8ac544e818d01a9533c9556d572d8366b91d6c1",   transactionIndex: 0,   v: "0x2a",   value: 200000 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i just started using web3, can you give me an idea about how to check each transaction ids inside a block and check if a particular transaction is verified and confirmed? I am not able to find out which web3 functions to use to get that data... Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi i am getting in console log : null null 0 when i try to run this simple command :

web3.eth.getTransaction('0xc649d5b2194b5e107563e5b4c0590bd60d193ff133afdd8de4d6020975163073', (err, result) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("result : "+result);
    }
});                                                                                                                              geth --rpc is running on localhost:8545 , can you please tell me what is wrong in the code ?

Comment: Try using ECMA5 notation (use `function` instead of fat arrow notation). Also, double check your transaction hash. I updated the answer with an example `getTransaction` output.

Comment: I copy pasted the above commands in terminal while running "geth console" but i got null when i typed res variable, same thing happens with web3js api, Maybe it has to do something with geth? because when i see the latest block number from localhost:8454 it show 0 as the latest block number, so maybe i need to synchronised it fully to get it working ?

Comment: Yes, your geth node has to be synced.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the callback function:

Use

```bash
geth console
# You can also use attach + online providers
# geth attach https://eth.getblock.io/token/mainnet/ 

web3.eth.getBlock(eth.blockNumber)
```